# Getting Notices while trying to fetch data from JSON Using PHP

Tags: php, json

I fetched some data using JSON. Then I converted the result to PHP Array using json_decode(). Now, I am trying to get some value.  I am getting notices.

```
$html = $curl->get($url);     // $html contains json result
$result = json_decode($html); //converting to php array
//the output is something like this
{
    "query":
        "results":{
           "Result":[
            {
              "BusinessUrl":"http://www.aplus.net/",
               -----------
               ------------
             }]
}
```

Now, if I try to fetch the business url like this

```
$result->query->results->Result[0]->BusinessUrl
```

which gives notices like

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

Please help me in this.

Comment: `var_dump($html)` What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

$result->query->results->Result[0]['BusinessUrl']

My guess is once you hit an array in JSON you're stuck accessing everything from an array instead of an object.

Comment: Spot on. "Result" is an array of objects. You either need to enumerate through them or pick them via array indices.